# DynamoDB: Is adding an item using list_append atomic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, atomic, database-concurrency, distributed-database

The [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/) for DynamoDB says:

> Q: Does DynamoDB support in-place atomic updates?
>
> Amazon DynamoDB supports fast in-place updates. You can increment or
>   decrement a numeric attribute in a row using a single API call.
>   Similarly, you can atomically add or remove to sets, lists, or maps.
>   View our documentation for more information on atomic updates.

When you click the link for more documentation, it has no more info about adding to sets.

Based on this I would think adding to a list/set using the `ADD` keyword would be atomic.

But would adding to a list using the `list_append` function also be atomic?  Is there any other documentation about this?

Answer (score 3):

All single-item updates to items using the UpdateItem API are atomic. Therefore, using `list_append()` in an UpdateExpression is also atomic.